# android sqlite problem

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey i recently started android development and encountered a problem when saving/loading data from a database. I took the database class from [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo_database) with some slight changes.

My problem is i got an activity with some edittexts. At onCreate the strings from the database should be written into the edittexts and when pressing the button the data in the database should be updated and activity closed. For the case that the database is empty I added an if-clause with cursor.getCount!=0 for reading the database, but this condition never gets true.

Here is my code

```
package com.gabrielisonline.timetable;

public class DurationActivity extends Activity {

DbAdapter dba;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.duration);

    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.duration_button1);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new SaveButtonListener());

    dba = new DbAdapter(this);
    dba.open(); 
    Cursor c = dba.fetchAllDurations();

    if (c.getCount() != 0)  {
        int i = c.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_TIME);

        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_length)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(0).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson1)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(1).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson2)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(2).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson3)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(3).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson4)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(4).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson5)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(5).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson6)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(6).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson7)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(7).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson8)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(8).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson9)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(9).getString(i));
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson10)).setText(dba.fetchDuration(10).getString(i));
    }


}

public class SaveButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String l = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_length)).getText().toString();
        String l1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson1)).getText().toString();
        String l2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson2)).getText().toString();
        String l3 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson3)).getText().toString();
        String l4 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson4)).getText().toString();
        String l5 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson5)).getText().toString();
        String l6 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson6)).getText().toString();
        String l7 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson7)).getText().toString();
        String l8 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson8)).getText().toString();
        String l9 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson9)).getText().toString();
        String l10 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.duration_lesson10)).getText().toString(); 

        dba.updateDuration(0,l);
        dba.updateDuration(1,l1);
        dba.updateDuration(2,l2);
        dba.updateDuration(3,l3);
        dba.updateDuration(4,l4);
        dba.updateDuration(5,l5);
        dba.updateDuration(6,l6);
        dba.updateDuration(7,l7);
        dba.updateDuration(8,l8);
        dba.updateDuration(9,l9);
        dba.updateDuration(10,l10);             

        dba.close();

        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Thanks for your answers guys. The problem was indeed thet I didn't really write something into the databse. Instead of just using updateDuration i changed the code in the onClick method to:

```
if (c.getCount() != 0)  {           
dba.updateDuration(1,l);
dba.updateDuration(2,l1);
dba.updateDuration(3,l2);
dba.updateDuration(4,l3);
dba.updateDuration(5,l4);
dba.updateDuration(6,l5);
dba.updateDuration(7,l6);
dba.updateDuration(8,l7);
dba.updateDuration(9,l8);
dba.updateDuration(10,l9);
dba.updateDuration(11,l10); 
} else {
dba.createDuration(l);
dba.createDuration(l1);
dba.createDuration(l2);
dba.createDuration(l3);
dba.createDuration(l4);
dba.createDuration(l5);
dba.createDuration(l6);
dba.createDuration(l7);
dba.createDuration(l8);
dba.createDuration(l9);
dba.createDuration(l10);
}
```

Now everything is working. I thought the update method would be enough also for the first write to the db (createDuration calls the create method on the database in DbAdapter and updateDuration calls update).

Comment: Please post more details on the error. What error/exception you get? Which line in the code does the error happen? And where are you writing data to the database?

Comment: There is no exception. The problem is that the database is never read. For example when I open the activity, write something into the edittexts, press save and then reopen the activity, onCreate should write the just saved strings back into the edittexts, but the edittexts are empty. I write the data with dba.updateDuration. If you want I can post the database code, but as said it's mostly the same as in the link above, except I got one column less and changed some names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever written anything to the DB? do you know that the DB definitely has data in it? If not try installing a SQLLite browser such as http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ and have a look at the tables.

That should help you identify if the problem is with writing to the table or reading from it. Might be able to help further if you provide your DBAdapter class

Answer (score 0):

If your cursor is not getting any values, it might mean that the database doesn't have any values. Also one error I noticed in your code is that after you get the database values into a cursor, you have to call

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

to move the cursor pointer to the first record. If you do not move the pointer, it is by default pointing to the position -1. Only after that can you call c.getString(1) to get the values.